# One to zero or one relationship Entity Framework, getting the relation of an entity

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to establish a one to zero or one relationship in EF Core, but I can't seem to go into a model and get it's related model.

```
public class Voucher
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long voucherId { get; set; }
    public long number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int paymentId { get; set; }

    public Invoice invoice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("client")]
    public long clientFK { get; set; }
    public Client client { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("voucher")]
    public long voucherFK { get; set; }
    public long invoiceId { get; set; }
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal amountTotal { get; set; }
    public string specification { get; set; }
    public string invoicePdf { get; set; }
    public long orderId { get; set; }

    public Voucher voucher { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InvoiceLine> invoiceLines { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceLine>();
}
```

Now I can create Vouchers without the need for an invoice, and unnable to create an invoice without a voucher. (I've also tried several other ways to map this relationship)

The problem is when I'm trying to fetch invoices that are bound to vouchers or the other way around.
Here's an example of how I tried to do it:

```
[HttpGet("testing1")]
public List<Voucher> getInvoiceTest(string filter)
{
    long tenantId = getTenantId();
    DateTime comparisonDate = compareDates(filter);
    var invoices = _warehouseDb.Invoices
        .Where(v => v.voucher.client.tenantFK == tenantId)
        .Where(d => d.voucher.date >= comparisonDate)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.voucher.paymentId).ThenByDescending(d => d.voucher.date)
        .ToList();
    //return invoices;

    List<Voucher> vouchers = new List<Voucher>();
    for (int i = 0; i < invoices.Count - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (invoices[i].voucher != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i value: " + i);
            Voucher voucher = new Voucher();
            voucher = invoices[i].voucher;
            vouchers.Add(voucher);
        }
    }
    return vouchers; 
}
```

I've tried without the ending forloop to see if I actually get a list of invoices, and I do. The filter part is just to get it within the correct time-span.

Once I reach the forloop, it can't seem to get any vouchers connected to any of the invoices.

Have I connected the models wrong or what's going on? This exact type of code works for other models where the relationship is one-to-many.

I've also tried mapping the models with virtual tag to see if it made any difference.  I also had invoices save a FK for vouchers, but my main goal is to go through a list of vouchers and get it's invoice.

Any suggestion is appreciated, if not, thanks for reading.

I'm using Entity framework core and postgreSQL

Comment: Comment out the WHERE statements and see if you are getting results.  Usually errors like this is due to the where.

Comment: It depends on which version of EF, but I would `.Include(c=>c.voucher)` the child objects as part of the initial query.

Comment: Oh yes, completely forgout about include, I'll test that out! @Neil

Comment: I can try that aswell @jdweng, thanks for the replies!

Comment: Okey so I've fixed the cycle error when using include, but now whenever I get into the forloop I get the whole object Invoice including voucher, instead of just a list of vouchers.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question according to the new insights and the new question arising from them.